# Using information from AuthenticatedPrincipal instead of request parameters or path variables in REST API

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, spring-security

Everything I have practiced in a professional setting has always involved having an ID that is associated with an entity, whether it be the actual user id or the id of the resource, and sometimes both get passed into the endpoint as either a request parameter or path variable. A lot of the time this seemed to be counterproductive because the user would need to already be authenticated through the spring security filter and have the proper role prior to even getting inside the endpoint. Then once inside the endpoint, we would do another check to make sure that the id that was passed as a request param or path variable, matched the one that was on the authenticated user ... the whole thing would have resembled something like this:

```
    @PostMapping("/do-something")
    @Secured(RoleType.Names.SOME_ROLE)
    public ResponseEntity addNewClient(@RequestParam final String id)
    {
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        MyCustomPrincipal loggedInUser = (MyCustomPrincipal) authentication.getPrincipal();

        final String authenticatedId = loggedInUser.getUser().getId();

        if(!authenticatedId.equals(id))
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED).build();

        // Make some service call and do/get something for the id provided

        return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
    }
```

However, I am now working on a project of my own and have configured things where my custom principal which implements UserDetails can be passed in as such and I am really trying to figure out what would even be the purpose of having to force my endpoints to include the id as a request param or path variable in situations where I am needing the id of the authenticated user like above. Is there something that I am missing out on or is it not best practice to just pull that info off of the authenticated user? I believe it would make my endpoints and code look a lot cleaner but I don't want to go against best practices.

```
    @PostMapping("/do-something")
    @Secured(RoleType.Names.SOME_ROLE)
    public ResponseEntity addNewClient(@AuthenticationPrincipal MyCustomPrincipal principal)
    {
        final String id = principal.getUser().getId();

        // Make some service call and do/get something for the id provided

        return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
    }
```